# Does the CSS3 transition slow down a website?

Tags: performance, css, css-transitions, transition

I have currently added the **CSS3 transition** to my website.
I'm not shure if it is possible, that it slows down my website, but everything seems flickering and there's this "jerky behaviour" on the transitions and flash videos.

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 10.0.02.

I added following to my CSS stylesheet:

```
*:link, *:visited, *:hover, *:active, *:focus {
    -webkit-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear, border-color .25s linear;
    -o-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear, border-color .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear, border-color .25s linear;
    transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear, border-color .25s linear;
}
```

Can you tell me if it's rather my browser being slow or if it is the CSS I added and if, then what's the evidence?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's always your browser being slow but it's possible that it's the CSS rules that cause it. Have you tried removing the rules to see whether it gets any faster? That would be the logical first step to take

Comment: Which browsers/UAs are giving you poor performance? Android is known for its poor CSS3 transitions in 1.x and 2.x

Comment: @pekka It seems to be faster without the transitions..

Comment: @darryn.ten I edited my question, you will see that I'm using Mozilla Firefox 10.0.02

Comment: depends a lot, especially what's running with and on your browser. try other browsers, doesn't hurt to install all 5 major browsers for testing purposes. check if you have similar issues. also, it may be your PC. specs? if you don't mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you've added transitions to everything on those states.

I'd change:

```
*:link, *:visited, *:hover, *:active, *:focus {
```

to

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:focus, [...Other elements...] {
```

So it's more targetted. Otherwise when you move the mouse around, the hover state is triggered, causing the browser to have to check for a transition.

Comment: I have to point out (to people who don't know better) that **it's not the `*` selector that causes performance problems;** (it should be optimized out of the selectors anyway) the bottleneck falls squarely on applying the transitions to too many elements, and attempting to animate too many things as a result. You can do all kinds of basic stuff with the universal selector and browsers will catch up just fine, but *transitions* are costly.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do the transitions slow down *load* times at all? As in, when the client first makes a request, does it take longer to load the page?

Comment: Not really no. You can measure it using the Dev tools in Chrome for instance, but you likely won't see much difference. That of course depends on exactly what's happening on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Any kind of animation will add load to the graphics systems but if you're combining CSS transitions and plugins like Flash you will make the load worse (since the layers have to be combined). Is your flash wmode set to transparent? if so try using opaque since this will stop the flash animation from caring what's happening underneath (technically speaking it becomes an overlay in the video driver).