# How to transition padding smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to transition the padding of the image when clicking on the parent div. How can I do it effectively and what is a good way of doing it?

```js
const container = document.getElementById('modal-product-thumb-item');
const myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');

container.addEventListener('click', () => {
        myimg.classList.toggle('active-image-wrap');
    container.classList.toggle('makeg');
});
```

```css
#modal-product-thumb-item {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.active-image-wrap {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.makeg {
  border: 3px solid #ffaaff !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal-product-thumb-item" style="border-radius: 10px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background: tomato">
     
       <img id="myimg" class="thumb-image-wrap" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Umm. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: You should learn from / check your previous questions, you asked a very similar question (regarding the solution) 22 hours ago.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine is it a good practice to transition padding?

Comment: @Leith This is simple and I do not see why it would be an issue in your case. But if you do not like css transition, you can go with javascript but it will probably be less efficient and simple.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

code speaks for itself

JavaScript:

```
const image = document.querySelector('.image')
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    image.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    transition: padding 200ms;
}
.image.active {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add `transition` to both of your changed classes

```
.active-image-wrap {
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.makeg {
  border: 3px solid #ffaaff !important;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: is it a good practise to transition padding?

Comment: if you need it,  then yes i guess and check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516047/does-the-css3-transition-slow-down-a-website